# Change date from dd-MM-YYYY to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame which looks something like this

```
    co_stkdate returns
1:1  03-Apr-95   1.685
1:2  04-Apr-95   1.529
1:3  05-Apr-95
```

I want to convert it into

```
     co_stkdate returns
1:1  03-04-1995   1.685
1:2  04-04-1995   1.529
1:3  05-04-1995
```

I tried this

myfiles$co_stkdate<- format(as.Date(myfiles$co_stkdate, format="%d-%M-%Y"))

But this is giving me result like this

```
co_stkdate returns
1:1       <NA>   1.685
1:2       <NA>   1.529
1:3       <NA>   1.338
1:4       <NA>  -0.236
1:5       <NA>  -0.250
1:6       <NA>   0.053
>
```

Comment: I got this. Need to use %B instead of %M.

Comment: `library(lubridate)`  then `dmy("03-Apr-95")`

Comment: `%B` works, but it is actually for full month name. For abbreviation, you're supposed to use `%b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make it possible to change your date to an appropriate date format for R

```
dates <- c("03-Apr-95", "04-Apr-95")

newFormat <- as.Date(dates, tryFormats = c("%d-%b-%y"))

[1] "1995-04-03" "1995-04-04"
```

Then format it in the usual way

```
format(newFormat, "%d-%m-%Y")

[1] "03-04-1995" "04-04-1995"
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
co_stkdate <- c("03-Apr-95", "04-Apr-95", "05-Apr-95")

format(x = as.Date(x = co_stkdate,
                   format = "%d-%b-%y"),
       format = "%d-%m-%Y")
#> [1] "03-04-1995" "04-04-1995" "05-04-1995"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope this helps.